# Assert does not works in my Form

Tags: symfony

I have a strange problem using a form in Symfony 3.

And my Assert does not works in my entity file.

In "the developer tools" it show the phrase but in the view all is in blank.

```
<?php

namespace TestBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @UniqueEntity("name")
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.")
     */
    private $name;

     /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $sername;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set sername
     *
     * @param string $sername
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSername($sername)
    {
        $this->sername = $sername;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sername
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSername()
    {
        return $this->sername;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param integer $role
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
     public function getRoles()
    {
        return array($this->role);
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {

    }
    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My form Action ( I put required in false to use the symfony valid option):

```
 public function addAction(Request $request){
  $user = new User();
  $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
  ->add('Name', TextType::class,array('required'=> false,'empty_data'  => null))
  ->add('SerName', TextType::class,array('required'=> false,'empty_data'  => null))
  ->add('role', TextType::class,array('required'=> false,'empty_data'  => null))
  ->add('email', EmailType::class,array('required'=> false,'empty_data'  => null))
  ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, array(
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'first_name'  => 'pass',
            'second_name' => 'confirm',
            'required' => false,
        ))
  ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Post'))
  ->getForm();
   $form->handleRequest($request);
  if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
      //$user = new Users();
      // $form->getData() holds the submitted values
      // but, the original `$task` variable has also been updated
      $password = $form->get('password')->getData();
      $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
      $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user,$password);
      $user->setPassword($encoded);
      $user = $form->getData();

      // ... perform some action, such as saving the task to the database
      // for example, if Task is a Doctrine entity, save it!
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $em->persist($user);
      $em->flush();
      return $this->redirectToRoute('test_homepage');
  }

  //return $this->render('UserBundle:Default:add.html.twig');
  return $this->render("TestBundle:Default:add.html.twig",array("form"=>$form->createView()));

}
```

**EDIT (I PUT VIEW FILE):**
My view:

```
{%extends "principal.html.twig"%}

  {% block body %}
    {{parent()}}
    <h1> {% trans %}New User{% endtrans %}</h1>
  {{ form_start(form,{'attr':{'novalidate':'novalidate','role':'form'}}) }}
       {{ form_label(form.Name,'Username', {'label_attr': {'class': 'foo'}}) }}
       {{ form_widget(form.Name,{'attr':{'class':'form-control'}}) }}
       {{form_errors(form.Name)}}
       {{ form_label(form.SerName,'Last name', {'label_attr': {'class': 'foo'}}) }}
       {{ form_errors(form.SerName) }}
       {{ form_widget(form.SerName,{'attr':{'class':'form-control'}}) }}
       {{ form_label(form.role,'Role', {'label_attr': {'class': 'foo'}}) }}
       {{ form_errors(form.role) }}
       {{ form_widget(form.role,{'attr':{'class':'form-control'}}) }}
       {{ form_label(form.email,'Email', {'label_attr': {'class': 'foo'}}) }}
       {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr':{'class':'form-control'}}) }}
       {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
       {{ form_label(form.password.pass, "Password", {'attr':{'class':'form-control'}}) }}
       {{ form_errors(form.password) }}
      {{ form_widget(form.password.pass, {'attr':{'class':'form-control'}}) }}

      {{ form_label(form.password.confirm, "Confirm" , {'attr':{'class':'form-control'}}) }}
      {{ form_widget(form.password.confirm, {'attr':{'class':'form-control'}}) }}
       {{ form_widget(form.save, { 'label': 'Create User','attr':{'class':'btn btn-primary'}}) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
  {% endblock %}
```

[image]

[image: Symfony 3]

Comment: The problem is that your view doesn't show the errors? Show your view's code.

Comment: Exactly! Under the input must show them!

Comment: Show us the code of your view. The problem is probably there.

Comment: And, just for curiosity... Why do you have two @Assert\NotBlank in your User class?

Comment: What is your question? Your comments at the top are very vague. Which assert in your entity is not working? The profiler is showing errors but what is the issue? Are you wanting to see errors on your page?

Comment: @pogeybait the error is that i want is when I put submit and there is an input who is blank then under the input show the error like : "This value should not be blank" or "Please enter your name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [doc about form rendering](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html)
In your twig template, you have to display the errors by using

```
{{ form_errors(form.age) }}
```

Or the whole row (label , error message, inpout) with

```
{{ form_row(form.age) }}
```

Which is almost equal to

```
<div>
    {{ form_label(form.age) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.age) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.age) }}
</div>
```

In your case, it means you have to add form_errors this way:

```
   {{ form_label(form.Name,'Username', {'label_attr': {'class': 'foo'}}) }}
   {{ form_widget(form.Name,{'attr':{'class':'form-control'}}) }}
   {{ form_errors(form.Name) }}
```

Comment: Thanks the problem is that i do not have added    {{ form_errors(form.age) }} right?

Comment: Please see that i have edited the question and i put the view code.

Comment: I will edit my view and tell me if u can see why only email and role works?

Comment: it is OK now my addAction in the createFormBuilder it gives to the view the name: Name and not name as in the entity it is call....name...and not Name. I changed Name for name. SerName for sername,etc....